# how lando reply relates to ackbar statement?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086190/synopsis)

> Though Admiral Ackbar wants to abandon the attack, Lando convinces him that they must give Han and his party more time on Endor.

how lando reply relates to ackbar statement?

The movie dialog:

```
Lando: That blast came from the death star! That thing's operational!
Ackbar: All craft prepare to retreat.
Lando: We won't get another chance at this, Admiral.
Ackbar: We have no choice General Calrissian.
        Our cruisers can't repel power of that magnitude.
Lando: Han will have that shield down; we've got to give him more time.
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it: what is your question?

Comment: Please, can you tell us who recommended that you read IMDB.com movie reviews to learn English? We are very interested in the answer! Lando's reply does not appear in the cited text. We cannot read the entire movie review! If you have a specific question about English usage, please [edit] your question to tell us what it is.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - What makes you think the O.P. was asked to read movie reviews to learn English? Maybe the O.P. was simply trying to decide what movie to watch. Quite often, learners come up with these questions, not in the course of formal study, but from everyday interaction with the language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the learner is asking us to critique someone else's (very poor) writing. Either that or the learner's question amounts to proofreading, or, if we can guess at the learner's point of  difficulty, the answer could very well be opinion based. In sum, this is a very poor and unclear question.

Comment: People's names are written with the first letter capitalized. It's ***L**ando*.  Could you at least make an attempt to use proper English in regard to copying people's names?

Comment: @J.R. After what I thought was a spate of questions about the often very poorly written written reviews at IMDB, I (and a couple of other readers) wondered if some course or instructor was encouraging students to use IMDB as texts in learning English (which we might want to discourage.) However, after looking closely at this "spate" in Data Explorer, I now realize that nearly all of the IMDB-related questions come from [the same poster](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/36149/user36411?tab=questions) who tells us that he uses IMDB to expand his vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ackbar wants to abandon the attack. He believes that "power of that magnitude" (that is, the power of the blast) is so great that their cruisers cannot repel it.

Lando then says that Han "will have that shield down".

It is not clear to me how "shield" relates to the "blast", and it seems at first like a *nonsequitur*. But I assume the power that could produce the blast is the same power that could establish the shield, and that therefore the shield was thought to be impenetrable, judging from the power of the blast.  Lando's remark is that Han will have figured out a way to disable the shield. He will "have it (the shield) down".  It won't matter how impenetrable the shield may be if it is not even operational.